# jQuery mobile change the text value of a input button

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, button, jquery-mobile-button

I just started using jQuery version 1.9.1 and now I am unable to change the text value of a jQuery mobile button.  In my JSFiddle demo i have tried every possible way to change the value with no luck.

When I was using jQuery version 1.8.2 paired with jQuery Mobile version 1.2.0 the following code worked just fine to change the text value of a button.

```
$('#btnSubmit').prev('.ui-btn-inner').children('.ui-btn-text').html('test');
```

Does anyone know how to accomplish this with the newer version of jQuery?

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/austin350s10/guvgvu4t/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the val() of the button and then tell the jQM to **[refresh](http://api.jquerymobile.com/button/#method-refresh)** the button widget

```
$("#btnSubmit").val('test').button( "refresh" );
```

> Updated **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/guvgvu4t/1/)**